# Comparing two multidimensional arrays with a callback

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["x8hQz"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["2014-07-16"]=>
    array(20) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["latitude"]=>
        string(16) "39.9298775948310"
        ["longitude"]=>
        string(17) "-87.3510829502270"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["latitude"]=>
        string(16) "39.9298960856350"
        ["longitude"]=>
        string(17) "-87.3511097005120"
      }...
```

So each array contains a deviceID, list of dates, and a list of GPS locations for each date. Each day may have a differing number of GPS locations. The arrays are identical and I want to compare the array to itself and remove days/GPS location groups based on how well they match other days in the array so that when I am done one of the arrays only contains days that have unique lists of locations on a per device basis. I want to compare the days within the arrays and if each of the value pairs within a day are within x number of feet based on the GPS locations then I would discard the matching days data.

I was planning on doing a foreach through both arrays but as I have it setup now I only have one keypair for one day to compare all of the other keypairs to so I am not able to compare the entire day to the list of days in the other array.

```
foreach ($trackArray as $deviceKey => $deviceValue)
{
    //echo $deviceKey . $deviceValue . "\n";
    foreach ($deviceValue as $dateKey => $dateValue)
    {
        //echo $dateKey . $dateValue . "\n";
        foreach ($dateValue as $locationKey => $locationValue)
        {
            //echo $locationKey . $locationValue . "\n";
            //echo $trackArray[$deviceKey][$dateKey][$locationKey]['latitude'];
            foreach ($finalTrackArray[$deviceKey] as $finalDateKey => $finalDateValue)
            {
                //echo $finalDateKey . $finalDateValue . "\n";
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Impractical and Processing-Intensive but here is the solution to your first part of the question.

> The arrays are identical and I want to compare the array to itself and
>   remove days/GPS location groups based on how well they match other
>   days in the array so that when I am done one of the arrays only
>   contains days that have unique lists of locations on a per device
>   basis

The Code

```
$finalTrackArray = []; 
foreach ($trackArray as $deviceKey => $deviceValue) { 
    foreach ($deviceValue as $dateKey => $dateValue) { 
        foreach ($dateValue as $locationValue) { 
            $serializedLocationList[] = serialize($locationValue); # Collect serialized version of all location value: latitude and longitude
        }
        foreach (array_unique($serializedLocationList, SORT_STRING) as $serializedLocationValue) { 
            $finalTrackArray[$deviceKey][$dateKey][] = unserialize($serializedLocationValue);
        }
    }
} 
//echo '<pre>'.print_r($finalTrackArray,1).'</pre>';
```

Comment: What's a more practical and more resource savvy way to do it?

Comment: Dont know ... This was the hardest multidimensional array problem I have ever encountered .. I spent lot of time solving it .. Hope it worked for you ..

Comment: The issue with the code you provided is it just removes duplicate values when in actuality we need to look at the array, perform some math on each value pair within a date as compared to every other date value pair and then make a decision based on the outcome of that comparison.  The answer I seek and the one you present solve two different problems.

Comment: I think you will need to use your own innovation with this one... I don't think anyone will answer this question .. because it is quite much what you are asking for.